# How to get call_count after using pytest mocker.patch

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm using pytest-mocker to patch a function to mock away what it's doing. But I also want to know how many times it was called and its call args.

Some script:

```
def do_something():
    x = 42
    return calculate(x)

def calculate(num):
    return num * 2
```

The test:

```
def test_do_something(mocker):
    mocker.patch("sb.calculate", return_value=1)
    result = do_something()
    assert result == 1  # Assert calculate is mocked correctly and returned whatever what I set above
```

This helped me mock away the call but I want to know during the test how many times calculate was called and its call arguments. Struggling to see how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
mock_calculate = mocker.patch("sb.calculate", return_value=1)
assert mock_calculate.call_count == 1
```

Or if you want to check what parameters were passed:

```
mock_calculate = mocker.patch("sb.calculate", return_value=1)
assert mock_calculate.called_once_with(1)
```