# How to mock test wait_until logic in a python3 using pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I am trying to implement a unit test for the wait_until function. However, I don't have api_key. call_api function is auto-generated. Sometimes get_api can have multiple required parameters. I want to test if get_api function can be called using a fake response.id. The test should fail if there is a missing parameter. Is it possible to create a mock test to achieve that?

```
 def call_api(api_key, wait):
    response = api(api_key)
    if wait:
         try:
            result = wait_until(get_api(response.id), state='Success')
        except Exception:
                raise
    print Success
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get call\_count after using pytest mocker.patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803679/how-to-get-call-count-after-using-pytest-mocker-patch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can achieve that with [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/).

You can write a test like this:

```py
def test_call_api(mocker):
    mocker.patch(
        'my_module.main.api',
        return_value="mocked_value"
    )
    mocker.patch(
        'my_module.main.get_api',
        return_value="mocked_value"
    )

    expected = "expected_value"
    actual = call_api(api_key, wait)
    assert expected == actual
```

Please check [this guide](https://changhsinlee.com/pytest-mock/).

Comment: this is not a proper answer, hence the downvote

Comment: I have added an example to improve it.